# SYNC SFSE X SFMC: Error by updates records

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sync

The Data Integration Between Service Cloud and Marketing Cloud not put all records. In the SFSE the number of accounts is 4.097 and in SFMC appears 2.9 like records sync. I dont understand why cause one week ago was perfect. 
In data sources the error description is "identity data updates failed".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are using the [latest](https://sfdc.co/MCC) MC Installed Package for Salesforce and check if your stack has been affected by [performance issues](https://trust.marketingcloud.com/).

These two in my experience have generally been the main reasons why Synchronised Data Extensions can have errors.